# Can we verify BLS signature in Solana Program.?

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, signature

Is it feasible to verify the BLS signature in the Solana program. I am exploring the "blst" crate of rust as of now but it would be better if I am aware of the feasibility beforehand and some guidance or reference in similar direction would be of great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/20241